# How do I insert a bash variable into the JSON body of a cURL request?

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to run the following cURL command (taken from the ArgoCD [documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer-guide/api-docs/)).

```
$ curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d $'{"username":"admin","password":"password"}'
```

With the proper credentials entered manually, it runs fine, but I have my password stored in an environment variable (`$PASSWORD`) and with the both the `'` and `"` quotes it does not insert the password correctly.

```
$ curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d $'{"username":"admin","password":"$PASSWORD"}'
```

I suspect it uses the string literal `$PASSWORD` as the actual password, rather than the variable's content.
How would I insert this variable correctly?

Comment: Variables don't expand inside [ANSI-C quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), only escape sequences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d '{"username":"admin","password":"'$PASSWORD'"}'
```

or this:

```
curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d "{\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\"}"
```

this'll probalby works too:

```
curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d "{'username':'admin','password':'$PASSWORD'}"
```

or:

```
printf -v data '{"username":"admin","password":"%s"}' "$PASSWORD"
curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d "$data"
```

Comment: In the first one, you want `'{...,"password":"'"$PASSWORD"'"}'` with the variable double quoted.

Comment: These won't work properly if the password contains any characters that need to be escaped in JSON data. It's safer to use a tool like `jq` that knows how to produce valid JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to create the JSON:

```sh
json=$(jq -c -n --arg username admin --arg password "$password" '$ARGS.named')

curl $ARGOCD_SERVER/api/v1/session -d "$json"
```

Using `jq` ensures that the JSON is properly formulated, no matter the contents of the variable:

```
$ password=$'with\'both"quotes'
$ declare -p password
declare -- password="with'both\"quotes"
$ jq -cn --arg username admin --arg password "$password" '$ARGS.named'
{"username":"admin","password":"with'both\"quotes"}
```